# Cannot find module 'expo-react-native-adapter' from 'setup.js'

Tags: unit-testing, react-native, jestjs, expo, enzyme

When I am running the test suite on the react-native code of my Expo App, I get this:

[image: Errorr in console]

But I don't understand why this is happening. The testing was working fine yesterday.

This is the test code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import App from "../src/App";

test("should render App component correctly", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same after updating Expo. Simply running `npm i expo-react-native-adapter` fixed this for me.